# CSS Sprite Image Background Issue

Tags: html, css, css-sprites, sprite

I am using sprite image for my website, My Icons are stacked horizontally and vertically.

The issue is when i try to use one particular sprite icon from the sprite image, I am not able to use only the corresponding sprite icon(rounded in blue in SS below) instead i got the entire image is spanning my div as below in Screenshot

I want to use only the particular Icon in left of text using padding-left (i gave 30px). I tried using background-size also, it is not working.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance for any help. 
My code is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--START: Adding of javaScript library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--END:   Adding of javaScript library-->

        <style>
            .sprite{
                background:url("images/css-sprite.gif") no-repeat scroll -165px -18px transparent;
                padding-left:30px;
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="">
            <div class="sprite">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]
See this JS BIN Demo http://jsbin.com/yojaj/1/edit

Comment: Unfortunately I can't fix the width for the content. Also i can't change this HTML structure. Need to fix via only CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add width and height rules in the sprite class to match the size of the icon in the sprite that you need.

Also try adding the icon as a pseudo element - like so:

```
.sprite:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food") -50px -50px no-repeat transparent;
    margin-right:5px;
    color:red;
    width: 20px;
    /* icon width */
    height: 20px;
    /* icon height */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/QW6e9/)**

Comment: :Thanks For the help. Unfortunately I can't fix the width for the content. Also i can't change this HTML structure. Need to fix via only CSS.

Comment: @MohamedHussain - I updated my answer - see if that works for you

Comment: Thanks For the Answer, now it is working good from IE8 and only problem i am facing in IE7 alone, everything perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify width and height for the .sprite class e.g

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
        <head>
            <!--START: Adding of javaScript library -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!--END:   Adding of javaScript library-->

            <style>
                .sprite{
                    background:url("images/css-sprite.gif") no-repeat scroll -165px -18px transparent;
                    padding-left:30px;
                    width:10px;
                    height:20px;
                    color:red;

                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="">
                <div class="sprite">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
            </div>  
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: :Thanks For the help. Unfortunately I can't fix the width for the content. Also i can't change this HTML structure.

Comment: Add a span element inside the div and set .sprite class to that, that way you won't change the main DIV

Comment: :Thanks For the help. Unfortunately I can't fix the width for the content. Also i can't change this HTML structure.Need to fix via CSS alone

Answer (score 1):

**used to this**

Define your html **sprate icon** class as like this

```
.sprite{
  background:url("images/css-sprite.gif") no-repeat scroll -165px -18px transparent;
  padding-left:30px;
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
 }
```

---

```
<div class="">
  <div>
     <span class="sprite"></span>  // add this icon try this way
     Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**------------------
------------------Updated**

**than do this only for css**

```
.sprite{
position:relative;
}
.sprite:after{
  content:"";
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
  background:url("images/css-sprite.gif") no-repeat scroll -165px -18px transparent;
  padding-left:30px;
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
 }
```

Comment: :Thanks For the help. Unfortunately I can't fix the width for the content. Also i can't change this HTML structure.Need to fix via CSS alone

Comment: @MohamedHussain check to my Updated answers you can do this only css as like this my answer updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <!--START: Adding of javaScript library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--END:   Adding of javaScript library-->

    <style>
        .sprite{
            background:url("images/css-sprite.gif") no-repeat scroll -165px -18px transparent;
            margin-right:30px;
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="">
     <div class="sprite"></div><p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks For the help. Unfortunately I can't fix the width for the content. Also i can't change this HTML structure.Need to fix via CSS

Comment: @MohamedHussain It will be better if you create a fiddle (along with your sprite image). So we can know whats exactly going wrong.